# Allow other users to cancel jobs

Tags: slurm

I have a test cluster with Slurm in which I would like that other users where able to cancel other users' jobs.

By default, the users are able to cancel their own jobs.
How can I define several administrators?

My Slurm configuration is:

```
ClusterName=Cluster
SlurmUser=user1
SlurmdUser=user1
AuthType=auth/none
CryptoType=crypto/openssl
JobCredentialPrivateKey = /state/partition1/scratch/slurm/confdir/slurm.key
JobCredentialPublicCertificate = /state/partition1/scratch/slurm/confdir/slurm.cert
SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmdDebug=3

StateSaveLocation=/state/partition1/scratch/slurm/var
SlurmdSpoolDir=/state/partition1/scratch/slurm/var/slurmd.%n
SlurmctldPidFile=/state/partition1/scratch/slurm/var/slurmctld.pid
SlurmdPidFile=/state/partition1/scratch/slurm/var/slurmd.%n.pid

SchedulerType=sched/backfill
JobCompType=jobcomp/filetxt
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/filetxt
AccountingStorageLoc=/state/partition1/scratch/slurm/var/accounting
JobCompLoc=/state/partition1/scratch/slurm/var/job_completions

FastSchedule=1
SlurmctldLogFile=/state/partition1/scratch/slurm/var/slurmctld.log
SlurmdLogFile=/state/partition1/scratch/slurm/var/slurmd.%n.log
ReturnToService=1

PriorityType=priority/multifactor
```

Answer (score 1):

Only operator or admin can cancel other users jobs:

Look at the `scancel` section in SLURM doc (under authorization). 
https://slurm.schedmd.com/scancel.html#lbAH

> When using the Slurm db, users who have AdminLevel's defined (Operator
>   or Admin) and users who are account coordinators are given the
>   authority to invoke scancel on other user's jobs.

Comment: So, without the DB I cannot define administrators...

Comment: I am not 100% certain but as far as I know yes you will need slurmDBD running.